# Store Maven Archetype In Google Cloud Storage

Tags: maven, maven-archetype, maven-wagon-plugin

I am using a Maven wagon to store my artifacts in Google Cloud Storage. I followed this blog post https://egkatzioura.com/2018/04/09/host-your-maven-artifacts-using-google-cloud-storage/. I wanted to avoid using nexus for the overhead of running a server and the storage cost savings I could get from GCS.

Now I am creating some Maven Archetypes I'd also like to store this in GCS and have people be able to generate the archetype on their machines.

I have been unable to find any help on how I can do this, is it possible to use a wagon for your general settings and pull archetypes from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to solve my own questions. I needed to add the Google Wagon jar to my Maven lib directory. I also added an archetype profile to my .m2/settings.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
       <id>Archetype</id>
       <repositories>
          <repository>
             <id>archetype</id>
             <url>gs://my-archetype-bucket</url>
             <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
             </releases>
             <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
             </snapshots>
          </repository>
          <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
          </repository>
       </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>Archetype</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```